# Disabling email for Prometheus Alertmanager based on severity

Tags: alerts, prometheus, alertmanager

We are monitoring a HPC computing cluster using a combination of Prometheus, Alertmanager and Grafana. On our machines, things like SWAP memory filling up to essentially the limit happen frequently, and while it is useful to see the corresponding `info`-level alerts in the Grafana Alerts dashboard, we would preferably not send the corresponding emails.

Is there a way to mute/disable all, say, alerting emails that have severity `info` in the `alertmanager.yml` config file?

The alerts are all defined similar to this one (adjusted from https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html):

```
  - alert: HostSwapIsFillingUp
    expr: (1 - (node_memory_SwapFree_bytes / node_memory_SwapTotal_bytes)) * 100 > 95
    for: 60m
    labels:
      severity: info
    annotations:
      summary: Host swap is filling up (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
      description: "Swap is filling up (>95%)\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}"
```

and the corresponding section in the `alertmanager.yml` file reads

```
  routes:
    - match:
        severity: 'warning'
      repeat_interval: 24h
      continue: true
    - match:
        severity: 'info'
      repeat_interval: 24h
      continue: true
      receiver: dropped

receivers:
  - name: 'admin-mails'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'admins@DOMAIN'
  - name: 'dropped'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'admins@DOMAIN'
```

Is there a possibility to make sure that the `info`-level alerts never cause emails while simultaneously still having them "fire", so that Grafana will display them?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial-and-error, the following seems to do the trick:

```
  routes:
    - match:
        severity: 'warning'
      repeat_interval: 24h
      continue: true
    - match:
        severity: 'info'
      repeat_interval: 24h
      continue: true
      receiver: dropped

receivers:
  - name: 'admin-mails'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'admins@DOMAIN'
  - name: 'dropped'
```

So the idea is to simply have the receiver unconfigured. With this, no emails are generated anymore, but the alerts are still shown in Grafana.

I will leave this here in case someone else encounters the same question.